# Connect Azure Data Factory to https://make.powerapps.com/

Tags: cloud, azure-data-factory, powerapps

I have created some tables in my Powerapps account (https://make.powerapps.com/). I would like to read this data in my Azure Data Factory for further processing. I could not find any options or documentations for this.

Is it generally possible to connect Azure Data Factory to Powerapps?

BR

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/export-to-data-lake-data-adf - Did you check this document?

Comment: @Aswin thank you for your comment. The instruction is telling me to select Common Data Model, but this option is not even available in the drop down...

Comment: Do you have required [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/export-to-data-lake-data-adf#prerequisites)?You need Azure synapse link for dataverse